# My Esc+<left arrow> deletes 3 lines in vim

Tags: vim, vimrc, vim-plugins

I am somewhat confused as what can be the cause of it. I disabled everythin in vim (replaced .vimrc with a blank file) and still, when I press Esc+left, I delete the 3 lines above my cursor, and with Esc+left, I delete the 3 lines below AND I end up in Insert mode.

I have started vim in verbose mode to see more info, but all I am getting is:

```
Executing CursorMoved Autocommands for "*"
autocommand call s:Highlight_Matching_Pair()
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Executing CursorMoved Autocommands for "*"
Press ENTER or type command to continue
autocommand call s:OnCursorMovedNormalMode()
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Executing TextChanged Autocommands for "*"
Press ENTER or type command to continue
autocommand call s:Highlight_Matching_Pair()
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Executing TextChanged Autocommands for "*"
Press ENTER or type command to continue
autocommand call s:OnTextChangedNormalMode()
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Is there anyway to debug this and see where this behaviour comes from? I also deleted my .vim/ folder to make sure no plugin was interfering.

Thanks~!

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed this is produced by my Terminal Emulator, Terminator. More info coming.

UPDATE: 
I had the following configuring line in my .tmux.conf:

`set-window-option -g xterm-keys on`

This made the terminal print the  keys every time I press ESC+. This of course, made vim delete lines.